# is the fixed point locus integral and reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$ of characteristic zero and let $G$ be finite group acting on $X$. Then one can define the scheme $X^G$ of fixed points of $X$. It is a closed smooth subscheme of $X$.

Now assume that (1) $X$ is a variety, that is, a reduced, integral scheme of finite type, and (2) $X$ is smooth. Then $X^G$ is known to be smooth. But is it true that $X^G$ is also a variety (i.e. integral and reduced)?

Comment: $X^G$ is certainly not smooth if you make no hypotheses on $X$.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention I was assuming $X$ to be smooth. Then $X^G$ is smooth.

Comment: It's edited now

Comment: As abx says, certainly $X^G$ need not be connected.  However, if $G$ is a $p$-group, then there is Smith theory.

Answer (score 2):

Strange question : being smooth, $X^G$ is certainly reduced! On the other hand, it can be reducible -- e.g. if $X$ is a curve, $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ acting through an involution with some fixed points.